# Setting up mod_wsgi and pyramid on windows

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I have been trying to set up pyramid under mod_wsgi in windows. My app is a simple scaffold created with the command

```
..\Scripts\pcreate -s starter it
```

My httpd.conf file has the following directives

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so
WSGIScriptAlias /x "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator.TRANSGLOBAL/Desktop/env/pyramid.wsgi"
<Directory "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator.TRANSGLOBAL/Desktop/env">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So all of my application code is in the folder it. The mod_wsgi.so file is loaded into apache and the following example code works in pyramid.wsgi

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

But when i change the pyramid.wsgi code to point to my pyramid application in named "it"

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app
import os
import sys
application = get_app('C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.TRANSGLOBAL\Desktop\env\it\development.ini', 'main')
```

Apache logs produces the following error

```
File "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator.TRANSGLOBAL/Desktop/env/pyramid.wsgi", line 11, in <module>
application = get_app('C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator.TRANSGLOBAL\\Desktop\\env\\it\\development.ini', 'main')
File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pyramid-1.4-py2.7.egg\\pyramid\\paster.py", line 31, in get_app
app = loadapp(config_name, name=section, relative_to=here_dir, **kw)

raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
DistributionNotFound: it
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimentation i came to notice that all of the windows boxes (windows 7, windows 8 and windows server 2003) i used refused to use the files in the virtual env and looked for the it project files in c:/python27/Lib/sitepackages

The solution was setting up a dist package of my package

`..\Scripts\python setup.py sdist`

and then installing the application in dist folder just like any other application. My apache configuration remained the same.